# pygbag pygame.error: Parameter 'renderer' is invalid

Tags: python, pygame, pygbag

I'm trying to convert a Pygame  program to work as a web app with pygbag.
following all instructions, I changed the main.py file to run with asyncio. running the main file itself with python interpreter, and all works fine. but when I'm trying to run it with Pygbag and run the game via the local webserver, it's not working properly. In general, the browser "loading", but than nothing happened.

So i simplified the program, tried to see if it's can run, and run the pygbag on browser in debug mode, than i got the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QTf2.png)

I'm adding here the simplified code:

```py
import pygame, pygame.gfxdraw, random, asyncio

from pygame.locals import (
    RLEACCEL,
    K_UP,
    K_DOWN,
    K_RIGHT,
    K_LEFT,
    KEYDOWN,
    K_ESCAPE,
    QUIT
)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

# ===============  Change direction  ===============
def change_direction(direction, collision):
    if direction == 'up-right' and collision == 'right':
        direction = 'up-left'
    if direction == 'down-right' and collision == 'right':
        direction = 'down-left'
    if direction == 'up-left' and collision == 'left':
        direction = 'up-right'
    if direction == 'down-left' and collision == 'left':
        direction = 'down-right'
    if direction == 'up-right' and collision == 'top':
        direction = 'down-right'
    if direction == 'up-left' and collision == 'top':
        direction = 'down-left'
    if direction == 'down-right' and collision == 'bottom':
        direction = 'up-right'
    if direction == 'down-left' and collision == 'bottom':
        direction = 'up-left'

    return direction


# ===============  Ball  ===============
class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ball, self).__init__()
        # make round surface
        circle = pygame.Surface((30, 30), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(circle, 15, 15, 7, (255, 255, 255))
        pygame.gfxdraw.filled_circle(circle, 15, 15, 7, (255, 255, 255))
        self.surf = circle
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(center = (random.randrange(5,790), 550))

    def update(self, direction):

        if self.rect.right > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            direction = change_direction(direction, 'right')

        if self.rect.left < 0:
            direction = change_direction(direction, 'left')

        if self.rect.top < 0:
            direction = change_direction(direction, 'top')

        if self.rect.top > SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            direction = change_direction(direction, 'bottom')


        if direction == 'up-right':
            self.rect.move_ip(1, -1)
        if direction == 'up-left':
            self.rect.move_ip(-1, -1)
        if direction == 'down-right':
            self.rect.move_ip(1, 1)
        if direction == 'down-left':
            self.rect.move_ip(-1, 1)

        return direction


# ===============  Run the game  ===============




async def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT])
    pygame.display.set_caption("BreakBricks")

    ball = Ball()
    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(ball)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    running = True
    direction = 'up-right'

    while running:
        for x in pygame.event.get():
            if x.type == KEYDOWN:

                if x.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    running = False


            elif x.type == QUIT:
                running = False



        direction = ball.update(direction)
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        for spr in all_sprites:
            screen.blit(spr.surf, spr.rect)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)
        await asyncio.sleep(0)

asyncio.run(main())
```

According to the traceback, the error occurred while trying to create the circle object. but i don't know why.

1. Simplifying the code to the most basic, with just 1 object created and moving on the screen.
2. Tried to bring all the initiation of objects and groups into the main function - although running in python it's not necessary - doesn't help.
3. Running debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The renderer error seems to be an issue with pygame.gfxdraw, which is an "experimental" feature according to the [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/gfxdraw.html).

Replacing the pygame.gfxdraw functions with pygame.draw functions fixed this for me.

Comment: Many thanks. It works. than i had to make some changes with some other part of the code, but this solved the problem for me.